# String containing hashtag to reactjs element

Tags: javascript, html, regex, coffeescript, reactjs

Hi all I am using coffee script and ReactJS for my site. So far I have a smooth development until I encounter String with hashtag and then convert hash tag to react element

React ELEMENT

```
@HashtagLink = React.createClass
displayName: 'hashtag link' 
  render: ->
    React.DOM.a null,
      href:'/hashtag/' + @props.hashtag
      @props.hashtag
```

JS function

```
@hashTagToLink = (string) ->
  string.replace(/#(\S*)/g,'<a href="http://emilenriquez.com">$1</a>')
```

Sample String : `I am a string with #hashtag I want to be converted to link`

Desired Output: I am a string with [#hashtag](http://emilenriquez.com) I want to be converted to link

Current Output: `I am a string with <a href="emilenriquez.com">#hashtag</a> I want to be converted to string`

Answer (score 0):

Your `@hashTagToLink` is creating a string suitable for `innerHTML` rather than creating a React Element.

If you want it to return a react element, something like this should work:

```
@hashTagToLink = (string) ->
  newString = string.split(/#(\S*)/g)

  return React.DOM.div(null,
     newString[0],
     React.DOM.a({
        href: 'http://emilenriquez.com'
     }, newString[1]),
     newString[2],
  )
```

**An Alternative:** React components also, have a `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method, so if you **do** need to return the string as a DOM fragment. you can use:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ __html: @hashTagToLink() } />
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html